# Raphael- using transform to scale js paths- unexpected results

Tags: javascript, raphael, shapes

I'm using raphael for the first time, and have a svg that I used an online converter to convert to javascript paths. I'm now running into a problem- the paths all have a .transform on them, so I'm not able to scale them in my script (very puzzling to me- any new .transform of any scale makes them one or two px in each wide or tall.)

they all have something like this at the end of each path variable: myshape.transform("m83.018878,0,0,83.018878,-2814.2764,385.12103")

HOw might I get rid of this transform, or have a new one work in addition to of instead of replacing the existing one? or can I go about the scaling another way?  I don't need anything animated- just need to to scale for page layout.

Answer (score 0):

The current tranformation matrix is showing a *83 scale. Using `.transform` resets this transform and if you don't use the same order of scaling in your transform, the path will look quite small.

It will be hard to refactor the converting tool result code to directly have paths with coordinates already transformed

However, dynamically, you can get the transformed path string by using the `Raphael.transformPath` method. 
You will have to provide the current path string which is its `.attr("path")` and its current transformation string being its `.transform()`.

Another lighter way is to keep using the `transform` method but appending your transformation using the «...» string part to tell Raphael it has to reuse the previous transform string.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Appending the transformation does work to scale,so seems like a step in the right direction, but the prob is that is then scales each shape from the center.  The shapes are area borders on a map, and what I'm after is making the whole map smaller. Thought paper.setViewBox might do it, but so far no luck.

Comment: You can use `paper.setViewBox` to do zooming. You first have to read the previous viewbox value and reuse the two first values x and y and just change the two last width and height. Last parameter «fit» should be at false.

Comment: I was able to get the map to scale all together by using: var rsr = Raphael('map', '664.938', '774.286'); rsr.setViewBox(0,0,1100,1100,false); but for some reason a larger width and height make things smaller- even on a little test path w/o the matrix transform issue.And, the area the svg takes up is not shrinking with the paths, so the page layout is still a problem.  Seems I'm missing something very basic.  I'm looking for way to define a pixel width and height for the whole space the map would  take up on the page, and have it scale to that.